# Can I use BCP.exe to import Picture data?

Tags: sql-server, image, bcp

Can I use BCP.exe to import Picture data into SQL Server table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, should be able to - here's a site with example code:
http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/imageimportexport/

Example in case the link goes dead:

```
UPDATE dbo.PhotoLibrary
SET    Photo = (SELECT *
                FROM   OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\MyImage.JPG', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x)
WHERE  ImageName = 'MyImage'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure u can, but i would rather use something like this

```
CREATE TABLE PictureStore (
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [filename] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [created] [datetime] NULL,
    [picturedata] [varbinary](max) NULL,
)   

insert PictureStore (filename, created, picturedata) select '$(_FILENAME)', GETDATE(), BulkColumn from Openrowset ( Bulk '$(_FILENAME)', Single_Blob) as picturedata
```

And use BCP.exe to export picture data if u want

```
bcp "select top 1 picturedata from dbo.PictureStore order by created desc" queryout picturedata.zip -S fssrv -T -f bcp.fmt
```